# How can I have centered text and right-aligned image in the same element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some `th` elements with text in them that should be centered and they also contain images:

[image]

The up/down arrow graphic is a separate image.

**My question is, what is the simplest reliable way to position that image over to the right side of the `th` element while keeping the text centered?**

I'm open to using jQuery/JavaScript if there's a reasonably simple way to do it.

One caveat: I need the up/down graphic to be a separate image, not part of the header background.

```
        <th> 
          Title
          <img src='/images/sort_unsorted.jpg' /> 
        </th>
```

Comment: `<img src='...' style="float: right" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a good handle on positioning (if you don't want to use a background image) you'll have to wrap the content in a block level element, like a DIV. You can't use `position: absolute;` on child elements of a table cell.

So, I recommend something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <th>
            <div class="positioning">
                Left
                <div class="img">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="positioning">
                Center
                <div class="img">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="positioning">
                Right
                <div class="img">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td>Left</td>
        <td>Center</td>
        <td>Right</td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Imagine `<div class="img">&nbsp;</div>` is just a 12px x 12px image.

**CSS**

```
table {
    border: 10px solid rgb(230,230,230);
    color: white;
}
table thead th,
table tbody td {
    background: black;
    border: solid 1px white;
    font: bold 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
}
table thead th {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
table thead .positioning {
    padding: 10px 32px;
    position: relative;
}
table thead .img {
    background: red;
    height: 12px;
    margin-top: -6px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    width: 12px;
}
```

The important thing to remember here is that you give the left and right sides of the `positioning` div enough padding to make room for the image (ie: `padding: 10px 32px;`). Otherwise the image will overlap your text.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brandondurham/nXQeR/

Answer (score 5):

Just float the image to the right:

```
th img {
    float: right;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/ZxUMY/

Comment: Don't know how particular Ethan is, but just doing a float push the text away from perfect center.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly how did you want the text to be centered, equidistant from the left/right edges of the `th` or from the left edge of the `th` to the left side of the image? There is a small difference between the two since your image is relatively small, but still a discernible difference.

Equidistant to image, the solution is easy (as Marcus answered):

`th img { float:right; }`

Equidistant to `th` edges requires a bit more, since you need to break the image out of the page flow:

```
th {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}
th img {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  /* optional, for vertically centering the image
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-[image height/2]px;
  */
}
```

EDIT: fixed for positioning in a table cell (thanks Brandon), and here's a simple fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/brillyfresh/4LDZ9/

Comment: You can't actually use positioning in table cells.

Comment: Cursed tables, thanks for pointing that out! Easy enough if you change the th element to display:block though. Updated my answer, with a fiddle for POC.